# Slow hard drive?

Tags: hard-disk, smartctl

Some time ago I noticed, that my desktop has become slower, than usual. It looks like a source of troubles is the hard drive (there is no such issue with Live USB) - but I don't understand the reason for this. There is an info from `smartctl` - can anybody explain, what may be wrong?

```
smartctl --all /dev/sda

smartctl 6.1 2013-03-16 r3800 [x86_64-linux-3.8.2] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Scorpio Blue Serial ATA (AF)
Device Model:     WDC WD5000BPVT-00HXZT3
Serial Number:    WD-WXF1E62KSHM2
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 658207174
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    500 107 862 016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Sun May  4 23:07:15 2014 NOVT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (12060) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 120) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x7035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       8
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   178   177   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       2083
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       966
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       3887
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       966
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       48
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   185   185   000    Old_age   Always       -       46771
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   103   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       44
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3884         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2834         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the HDD is having to re-read either a bad block or bad sector, which is beginning to fail, it will try to re-read a given section several times until it's able to do so. This behavior will manifest as the HDD "slowing down" but it's the act of having to read a given area from the disk a multitude of times that you're experiencing.

Typically when this occurs I'll run the HDD through either [HDAT2](http://www.hdat2.com/) or [SpinRite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) to determine if there are any bad blocks on the disk and instruct either of these two tools to attempt to repair and/or recover the data from defective blocks.

This is only a short-term fix; typically if it continues to happen then it's oftentimes a symptom of a larger problem looming that the HDD is going to fail in the not-too-distant future. If this is the case then I would begin planning on getting a replacement and migrating the data from the problem drive before it actually fails.

Comment: Looks like you're right, but ``badblocks -sv /dev/sda`` doesn't show any bad block

Comment: `badblocks` isn't always able to detect HDD issues, only issues with the filesystem contained on the HDD.